# How to calculate Pearson's correlation coefficient in R for grouped data

Tags: r, correlation, pearson

How to calculate Karl Pearson's correlation coefficient "using R" for data with frequency distribution. Say, if we need to calculate the Pearson's coefficient for  data enclosed in the screenshot, how would we do it ??[image: Data for calculating Pearson's coefficient]

Comment: Pearson's correlations are generally not appropriate for frequency data. However, are you asking how to calculate the correlation between Age and Marks?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The requirement is to find correlation between Age & Marks.